# Is there a plugin available for recurring orders in Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I would like my customers to be able to fill their cart with products of their choosing, checkout, and then have this same selection of products be automatically checked out again for them every X days.

Use case:

> I would like you to deliver 4 x 2L Milk and 2 x 200g Cheese to me every week on Tuesdays. I will pay with cash on delivery.

Does anyone know of a plugin that can do this? I am aware of the subscription plugins available, but this doesn't create the order with the product amounts that the customer has chosen.

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Gavin! Is this in relation to a specific ecommerce/cart plugin you're already using, like woocommerce?

Comment: @mozboz Yes I am using woocommerce for the order processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with

https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/

It can be similar to Amazons " subscribe and save "

Here is also a Tutorial
https://jilt.com/blog/create-a-woocommerce-subscribe-and-save-system/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Damian, unfortunately it is not what I am after. In my case my subscriptions will be created at run time by the customers, instead of me predefining x number of subscription choices. For example one customer would want 3 x Milk cartoons every week, another would want 2 x cheese blocks every 2 weeks.